# Missmatch in array comparison error message ' Argument "" isn't numeric in array element at'

Tags: arrays, perl, perl-data-structures, type-mismatch

I am very new to perl and am struggling to get this script to work.

I have taken pieces or perl and gooten them to work as indivual sections but upon trying to blend them together it fails. Even with the error messages that show up I can not find where my mistake is.

The script when working and completed will read an output file and go through it section my section and utilmately generate a new output file with not much more the a heading with some additional text and a value of the amount of lines in that section.

My issues are when it does the looping for each keyword in the array it is now failing with the error message 'Argument "" isn't numeric in array element at'. Perl directs me to a section in the script but I can not see how I am calling the element incorrectly. All the elements in the array are alpha yet the error message is refering to a numeric value.

Can anyone see my mistake.

Thank you

Here is the script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
# this version reads each variable and loops through the 18 times put only displays on per loop. 

my $NODE = `uname -n`;
my $a = "/tmp/";
my $b = $NODE ;
my $c = "_deco.txt";
my $d = "_deco_mini.txt";
chomp $b;
my $STRING = "$a$b$c";
my $STRING_out = "$a$b$d";

my @keyword = ( "Report", "Last", "HP", "sulog", "sudo", "eTrust", "proftp", "process", "active clusters", "pdos", "syslog", "BNY", "syslogmon", "errpt", "ports", "crontab", "NFS", "scripts", "messages");

my $i = 0;
my $keyword="";
my $x=0;
my $y=0;
my $jw="";

my $EOS = "########################################################################";
my $qty_lines=0;
my $skip5=0;
my $skipcnt=0;
my $keeplines=0;
my @HPLOG="";

do {
    print "Reading File: [$STRING]\n";

    if (-e "$STRING" && open (IN, "$STRING")) {
#       ++$x;                              # proving my loop worked
#       print "$x interal loop counter\n"; # proving my loop worked
        for ( ++$i) { # working
            while ( <IN> ) {
                chomp ;
                #if ($_ =~ /$keyword/) {
                #if ($_ =~ / $i /) {
                #if ($_ =~ /$keyword[ $i ]/) {
                if ($_ =~ /$keyword $i/) {
                    print "  $i \n";
                    $skip5=1;
                    next;
#                   print "$_\n";# $ not initalized error when tring to use it 
                }

                if ($skip5) {
                    $skipcnt++;
                    print "SKIP LINE: $_\n";
                    print "Header LINE: $_\n";
                    next if $skipcnt <= 5;
                    $skip5=0;
                    $keeplines=1;
                }

                if ($keeplines) {
#                   ++$qty_lines;                # for final output
                    last if $_ =~ /$EOS/;
                    print "KEEP LINE: $_\n";
#                   print "$qty_lines\n";      # for final output

                    push @HPLOG, "$_\n";
                    # push @HPLOG, "$qty_lines\n";# for final output
                }
            } ## end while ( <IN> )
        } ## end for ( ++$i)
    } ## end if (-e "$STRING" && open (IN, "$STRING"))

    close (IN);
} while ( $i < 19 &&  ++$y < 18 );
```

Here is a sample section or the input file.
    ###############################################################################

```
                       Checking for active clusters.

                                @@@@@@@@@

  root 11730980 12189848   0 11:24:20  pts/2  0:00 egrep hagsd|harnad|HACMP|haemd

 If there are any processes listed you need to remove the server from the cluster.

############################################################################

                       This is the output from Pdos log

Please review it for anything that looks like a users may be trying to run something.

                                @@@@@@@@@

                        This server is not on Tamos 

############################################################################

                        This is the output from syslog.conf.

Look for any entries on the right side column that are not the ususal logs or location.

                                 @@@@@@@@@

# @(#)34    1.11  src/bos/etc/syslog/syslog.conf, cmdnet, bos610 4/27/04 14:47:53
# IBM_PROLOG_BEGIN_TAG 
# This is an automatically generated prolog. 
#  
# bos610 src/bos/etc/syslog/syslog.conf 1.11
```

I truncated the rest of the file

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. No, we can't see your mistake. Include your code with your question.

Comment: Yes, I can see your mistake. You are asking about code that you have not shown.

Comment: Here is the output error message as it fails.

Comment: This would be much easier if you told us the line number perl gives you in the error message.

Answer (score 10):

> Can anyone see my mistake.

I can see quite a lot of mistakes. But I also see some good stuff like `use strict` and `use warnings`.

My suggestion for you is to work on your coding style so that it gets easier for you and others to debug any problems.

## Naming variables

```
my $NODE = `uname -n`;
my $a = "/tmp/";
my $b = $NODE ;
my $c = "_deco.txt";
my $d = "_deco_mini.txt";
chomp $b;
my $STRING = "$a$b$c";
my $STRING_out = "$a$b$d";
```

Why are some of those names all uppercase and others all lower case? If you are building up a filename, why do you call the variable that holds the filename `$STRING`?

```
my @keyword = ( "Report", "Last", "HP", "sulog", "sudo", ....
```

If you have a list of several keywords, wouldn't it be apt to not chose a singular for the variable name? How about `@keywords`?

## Using temporary variables you don't need

```
my $NODE = `uname -n`;
my $a = "/tmp/";
my $b = $NODE ;
my $c = "_deco.txt";
chomp $b;
my $STRING = "$a$b$c";
```

Why do you need `$a`, `$b` and `$c`? The (forgive me) stupid names of those vars are a tell-tale sign that you don't need them. How about this instead?

```
my $node_name = `uname -n`;
chomp $node_name;
my $file_name = sprintf '/tmp/%s/_deco.txt', $node_name;
```

## Your biggest problem: you have no idea how to use arrays

You are making several drastic mistakes when it comes to arrays.

```
my @HPLOG="";
```

Do you want an array or another string? The `@` says array, the `""` says string. I guess you wanted a new, empty array, so `my @hplog = ()` would have been much better. But since there is no need to tell perl that you want an empty array as it will give you an empty one anyway, `my @hplog;` will do the job just fine.

It took me a while to figure out this next one and I'm still not sure whether I'm guessing your intentions correctly:

```
my @keyword = ( "Report", "Last", "HP", "sulog", "sudo", "eTrust", "proftp", "process", "active clusters", "pdos", "syslog", "BNY", "syslogmon", "errpt", "ports", "crontab", "NFS", "scripts", "messages");
...
                if ($_ =~ /$keyword $i/) {
```

What I *think* you are doing here is trying to match your current input line against element number `$i` in `@keywords`. If my assumption is correct, you really wanted to say this:

```
if ( /$keyword[ $i ]/ ) {
```

## Iterating arrays

Perl is not C. It doesn't make you jump through hoops to get a loop.

Just look at all the code you wrote to loop through your keywords:

```
my $i = 0;
...
        for ( ++$i) { # working
...
                if ($_ =~ /$keyword $i/) {
...
} while ( $i < 19 &&  ++$y < 18 );
```

Apart from the facts that your `working` comment is just self-deception and that you hard-coded the number of elements in your array, you could have just used a `for-each` loop:

```
foreach my $keyword ( @keywords ) {
    # more code here
}
```

I'm sure that when you try to work on the above list, the problem that made you ask here will just go away. Have fun.